# Emacs and Long Shell Commands

Tags: shell, emacs, elisp

Is there a way to run a shell command, have the output show up in a new buffer and have that output show up incrementally? Eshell and other emacs terminal emulators do a find job of this but I see no way to script them.

What I'd like to do is write little elisp functions to do stuff like run unit tests, etc. and watch the output trickle into a buffer.

The elisp function shell-command is close to what I want but it shows all the output at once when the process finishes.

Comment: Not quite what you need, but `M-x compile` shows compilation progress incrementally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [doublep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319799/doublep) mentioned, there is <kbd>M-x compile</kbd>, and there's also just the simple <kbd>M-x shell</kbd> and in that shell you run whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [comint-run](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Mode.html#index-comint_002drun-3633) to execute a command without needing to start a sub-shell first. I believe `M-x shell` uses comint mode with some modifications, so this won't be a whole lot different from that. But if you want to call a program directly and have its input and output be tied to a buffer, comint-run is the function to call. It is a little tricky to use, so read the documentation: `C-h f comint-run`.