# Run multi-string bash script from Emacs

Tags: shell, emacs, elisp, executable

I want to run the following bash script, that is stored in an Elisp string, not in a `.sh` file, then store the shell output in a variable.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
IFS=: read -ra _dirs_in_path <<< "$PATH"

for _dir in "${_dirs_in_path[@]}"; do
    for _file in "${_dir}"/*; do
        [[ -x ${_file} && -f ${_file} ]] && printf '%s\n' "${_file##*/}"
    done
done
```

I couldn't run `shell-command` on bash scripts, consisting of multiple strings. [Emacs and Long Shell Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2706171/596361) didn't help me either, as `compile` and `comint-run` also require commands, not bash syntax.

**How do i run a complex bash script from Elisp?**

Comment: if M-x shell-command-on-region fails, please send a bug report

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiline commands are fine to provide as an argument to `bash -c` if you quote them as you would any other shell argument that might contain shell metacharacters, e.g.:

```
(setq my-command
      (concat "IFS=: read -ra dirs <<<\"$PATH\"\n"
              "for dir in ${dirs[@]}; do\n"
              " echo got dir \"$dir\"\n"
              "done\n"))

(shell-command (format "bash -c %s" (shell-quote-argument my-command)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This will perhaps do what you want. Add modifiers to taste :)

```
(defun example-multiline-shell-command ()
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert "#!/bin/bash
IFS=: read -ra _dirs_in_path <<< \"$PATH\"

for _dir in \"${_dirs_in_path[@]}\"; do
    for _file in \"${_dir}\"/*; do
        [[ -x ${_file} && -f ${_file} ]] && printf '%s\n' \"${_file##*/}\"
    done
done")
    (write-region (point-min) (point-max) "~/temp.sh")
    (shell-command "source ~/temp.sh" (current-buffer))
    (buffer-string)))
```

<strike>**EDIT** Oh, and FYI `"${_dirs_in_path[@]}"` is going to end bad if files have spaces or other characters that might be treated as separators in the names.</strike>

Comment: No, the `"${arrayvar[@]}"` syntax is perfectly safe regardless of the presence of shell metacharacters in any element of `arrayvar`.

Answer (score 0):

`shell-command` actually works on multi-string bash syntax. My problem was that `shell-command` doesn't know bash environment variables, including PATH. What i did: replaced all `"` with `\"` in the script and put it in an elisp string, then assigned some directories to PATH. Here is the code, that successfully outputs all executables in the system to the `*Shell Command Output*` buffer.

```lisp
(let ((path "PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'")
      (command "IFS=: read -ra _dirs_in_path <<< \"$PATH\"

for _dir in \"${_dirs_in_path[@]}\"; do
    for _file in \"${_dir}\"/*; do
        [[ -x ${_file} && -f ${_file} ]] && printf '%s\n' \"${_file##*/}\"
    done
done"))
  (shell-command (concat path ";" command)))
```

I'm still interested in how to make `compile` work with multi-string bash scripts too.

**Note on PATH:** I didn't use `(getenv "PATH")` in the above solution because, as far as i understand, X display managers (including xdm, gdm and kdm) [do not run shell before Xsession](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9664872/596361), so an emacs run from GUI will have different environment variables from the bash ones. I run `emacs --daemon` on startup through cron, my paths are set up in `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`, so Emacs doesn't get its PATH from there.

Steve Purcell proposes a [code](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/init-exec-path.el) (see also variant [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2566945/596361) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609349/596361) of it on SO) to make sure Emacs has the same environment variables, including PATH, as the shell.